# Using tmux in VS Remote SSH session

Tags: visual-studio-code, tmux, vscode-remote

I am currently starting to work with SNNs on a GPU server. I am working with VS Code Remote-SSH package. Thereby, I'd like to use the tmux package to be able to start multiple processes which don't terminate when I disconnect the terminal from the server.

So far I used the https://cppdev.medium.com/vs-code-and-tmux-intergation-for-reliable-remote-development-e26594e6757a Tutorial. It already helps me that the process, I run doesn't shut down when I close the terminal but I didn't manage to start a second process on the server because each time, I open a new terminal, the already running process appears. What are your thoughts on that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is the desired behaviour. You will want to use tmux itself to manage multiple processes on the remote host. You can use `Ctrl-b c` (default keybinding) to create a new window inside tmux, all the windows inside tmux will be maintained on the remote server.

Comment: I know this answer will probably not help the original poster, but I came here from Google and figure I might be able to help some fellow Googlers